# Spring JPA @Query error: "unexpected token: OVERLAPS"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get every formations that overlap with a given an interval of years from my postgresql database. However, i get a syntax error message for my query validation when my beans are being initialized.

```
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: OVERLAPS
```

Caused by this part of my JPA repository

```java
@Query("SELECT f FROM formations f WHERE (SELECT (make_date(starting_year, 1, 1), make_date(ending_year, 1, 1)) OVERLAPS (make_date(:startingYear, 1, 1), make_date(:endingYear, 1, 1)))")
List<Formation> findAllMatchingFormations(@Param("startingYear") int startingYear, @Param("endingYear") int endingYear);
```

The thing is that the query works perfectly fine when i do it from inside the database.

There is the full stack trace

```
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: OVERLAPS
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.aliasedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2628) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectedPropertiesList(HqlBaseParser.java:1525) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1425) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1148) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:825) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.subQuery(HqlBaseParser.java:4356) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.primaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:1060) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3960) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3891) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.multiplyExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3767) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.additiveExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3393) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:682) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2998) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2824) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2783) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2693) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2653) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2331) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2079) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.whereClause(HqlBaseParser.java:540) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:831) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:294) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        ...
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

2022-07-01 14:32:04.107 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker        : line 1:163: unexpected token: ,
2022-07-01 14:32:04.108 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker        : line 1:163: unexpected token: ,

antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: ,
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:864) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:294) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:636) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        ...
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

2022-07-01 14:32:04.109 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker        : line 1:192: expecting EOF, found ')'
2022-07-01 14:32:04.109 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker        : line 1:192: expecting EOF, found ')'

antlr.MismatchedTokenException: expecting EOF, found ')'
        at antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211) ~[antlr-2.7.7.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:294) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        ...
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

2022-07-01 14:32:04.110  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'formationsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formationRepository' defined in FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository.findAllMatchingFormations(int,int); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository.findAllMatchingFormations(int,int)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository.findAllMatchingFormations(int,int)!
2022-07-01 14:32:04.111  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-07-01 14:32:04.113  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-07-01 14:32:04.115  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-07-01 14:32:04.117  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-07-01 14:32:04.127  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-07-01 14:32:04.148 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'formationsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formationRepository' defined in FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository.findAllMatchingFormations(int,int); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository.findAllMatchingFormations(int,int)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository.findAllMatchingFormations(int,int)!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        ...
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formationRepository' defined in FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository.findAllMatchingFormations(int,int); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository.findAllMatchingFormations(int,int)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository.findAllMatchingFormations(int,int)!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository.findAllMatchingFormations(int,int); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository.findAllMatchingFormations(int,int)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository.findAllMatchingFormations(int,int)!
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:107) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1061) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:365) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List FOC.FOC.Formations.FormationRepository.findAllMatchingFormations(int,int)!
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:51) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:169) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:253) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:103) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: OVERLAPS near line 1, column 123 [SELECT f FROM FOC.FOC.Formations.Formation f WHERE (SELECT (make_date(starting_year, 1, 1), make_date(ending_year, 1, 1)) OVERLAPS (make_date(:startingYear, 1, 1), make_date(:endingYear, 1, 1)))]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:757) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy106.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar!/:2.7.1]
        ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: OVERLAPS near line 1, column 123 [SELECT f FROM FOC.FOC.Formations.Formation f WHERE (SELECT (make_date(starting_year, 1, 1), make_date(ending_year, 1, 1)) OVERLAPS (make_date(:startingYear, 1, 1), make_date(:endingYear, 1, 1)))]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:636) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
        ... 74 common frames omitted
```

I tried to do a native query with nativeQuery=true and a SqlResultSetMapping annotation, but it gave me more complications and I think I am just missing something there to make it work.

I'm using:

```
Spring boot 2.7.1
Postgresql 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OVERLAPS` is not supported by JPQL queries (you can find [the list of supported functions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#jpql-standardized-functions) in the Hibernate ORM documentation).
It should work if you use a native SQL query:

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true, value="... <The SQL query>")
```

If you return all the columns with `select *`, you won't need to map the result using `SqlResultSetMapping`. Hibernate should be able to map each row to `Formation` automatically.